Why my NUnit test method always gets pass for some calculation functionality
I have scenario my unit test method should fail if I change the called/implementation of my presenter method. please see below, let me know if don't get this.
    public SaveActionResultWithCustomizedErrors<int> SaveOrderAllocation(OrderAllocation orderAllocation, FillOrderOutput fillOrderOutput)
    {
        var saveResult = new SaveActionResultWithCustomizedErrors<int>();

        int? maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty = null;
        
        //// this is the class where I need to pass orderAllocation greater of either 90% of the Order Allocation Qty OR Pre Order Demand (Open + Released + Shipped).          
        var title = new orderAllocationInput() {Ean = orderAllocation.Ean}; 

        try
        {
            //validate pre order allocation qty before sending to product master using isUnlimited flag.
            if (!orderAllocation.IsUnlimitedAllocation)
            {
                if (orderAllocation.PreorderAllocationQty != null &
                    orderAllocation.PreorderAllocationQty.HasValue)
                {
                    var preDemandQty = (fillOrderOutput.OpenQuantity + fillOrderOutput.ReleasedQuantity + fillOrderOutput.ShippedQuantity);
                    maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty = Math.Max(.9 * orderAllocation.PreorderAllocationQty.Value, preDemandQty).RoundToInt();
                }

                if (maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty != null) title.PreorderAllocation = maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty.Value;
            }
           
            ItemDao.SavePreorderAllocation(orderAllocation, fillOrderOutput);
            saveResult.SuccessfulItems.Add(orderAllocation.SystemId, orderAllocation.SystemId);

        }
        this works fine, now I'm looking for a NUnit test method to fullfill the above calculation.
        
        
        
    [Test]
    public void SaveOrderAllocation_With_OrderAllocationToMaxOf90Percent_Or_PreDemandQtyTest()
    {
        // Arrange
                    
        var orderAllocation = new OrderAllocation
        {
            Ean = "EAN123",
            Sysid = 1,
            PreorderAllocationQty = 100,
            IsUnlimitedAllocation = false
        };

        var fillOrderOutput = new FillOrderOutput
        {
            OpenQuantity = 80,
            ReleasedQuantity = 30,
            ShippedQuantity = 20
        };

        var preDemandQty = fillOrderOutput.OpenQuantity + fillOrderOutput.ReleasedQuantity + fillOrderOutput.ShippedQuantity;
        // The preDemandQty is 80 + 30 + 20 = 130
        // 90% of 100 = 90, so max(90, 130) = 130

        //var expected = (int) (testParameter.PreorderAllocationQty * .9); 
        var expected  = Math.Max(.9 * orderAllocation.PreorderAllocationQty.Value, preDemandQty).RoundToInt();

        // Act
        var result = Testee.SaveOrderAllocation(orderAllocation, fillOrderOutput);

        // Assert
        _itemDaoMock.Verify(x => x.SavePreorderAllocation(orderAllocation, fillOrderOutput), Times.Once());

        Assert.IsTrue(result.Success);
        Assert.That(result.FailedItems.Count, Is.EqualTo(0));
        Assert.That(result.SuccessfulItems.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, preDemandQty);  // 130
    }
    

Now, how do I Assert if calculation in method SaveOrderAllocation in my class gets change. like below
            if (!orderAllocation.IsUnlimitedAllocation)
            {
                if (orderAllocation.PreorderAllocationQty != null &
                    orderAllocation.PreorderAllocationQty.HasValue)
                maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty = (int?)(.9 * preorderAllocation.PreorderAllocationQty.Value);
                if (maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty != null) title.PreorderAllocation = maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty.Value;
            }

in this case my above Test method should fail? how do I assert without changing the method (SaveOrderAllocation) body. please help.
Thanks in Advance.

You can split out the validation logic so that it returns the maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty value. Depending on your setup this could a separate validator or just a separate method. Either way, you can test the method separately to ensure it's returning the expected value.

@sr28 can you please provide little bit of code sample.?

If you split out the validation logic into a separate public method (or perhaps a separate validator depending on your use case) you can test that logic separately:
public int? MaxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty(OrderAllocation orderAllocation, FillOrderOutput fillOrderOutput)
{
    if(orderAllocation.IsUnlimitedAllocation || orderAllocation.PreorderAllocationQty is null)
        return null;

    var preDemandQty = (fillOrderOutput.OpenQuantity + fillOrderOutput.ReleasedQuantity + fillOrderOutput.ShippedQuantity);
    maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty = Math.Max(.9 * orderAllocation.PreorderAllocationQty.Value, preDemandQty).RoundToInt();

    return maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty.Value;
}

In your other method you then just call it like this:
try
{
    var maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty = MaxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty(orderAllocation, fillOrderOutput);
    if (maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty != null) title.PreorderAllocation = maxOfNinetyPercentAllocationQty.Value;
       
    ItemDao.SavePreorderAllocation(orderAllocation, fillOrderOutput);
    saveResult.SuccessfulItems.Add(orderAllocation.SystemId, orderAllocation.SystemId);
}

Now that the validation logic is separated out you can write a test for that and ensure the expected value is returned.
